# I have code that is supposed to have a (very bad) AI place his O for tic-tac-toe in a random spot on the board

Tags: python, while-loop

But after I win the game, (I have computer print the number every time) the computer keeps picking numbers over and over trying to get a spot even though there are none left. I have no idea what to do, any help is greatly appreciated.

```
if board[computer] != 'X' and board[computer] != 'O':
        print computer
        board[computer] = 'O'
    else:
        while board[computer] == 'O' or board[computer] == 'X':
            computer = random.randint(0, 8)
            print computer
            if board[computer] != 'X' and board[computer] != 'O':
                board[computer] = 'O'
                break
```

Comment: Is this the entire code? I feel like there might be a bit more relevant code

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at your logic....

your while says...`board[computer] == 'O' or board[computer] == 'X'`

and your break if statement:

```
if board[computer] != 'X' and board[computer] != 'O':
```

Neither checks if the board is full.

You need to cycle through your 'board' and check if it is full

eg...

```
emptyposition = True
for position in board :
    if not position == Null : # Your board position is empty 
        emptyposition = False


if not emptyposition :
    break
```

Comment: I have my game set up so that the string is the board, so each spot has a number in it, IE 0 is the top left, 4 is the middle of the board, how would I go about doing that for that type of board? would I be able to put a range in there? like "if not position == (0, 9)" ? Or maybe possibly check to see if it is an integer? that would also work, but I don't know how to go about doing that.

Comment: Your board should have 9 places in it. It depends how you define it to start off with - from what you say you seem to have defined it as a 9 digit string, though it could be a list or an array - basically the same sort of thing...  In any case you need to define what the string says if it hasn't got an x or an o in it - whether it is NULL - for something nullable, - or zero for something integer, or eg '-' for a string.  Then you need to insert the code above into your while loop to allow you to break out of it if there is no 'empty' space in your board.

Comment: well the way I have my board set up is like 
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

Comment: Sorry I think maybe I misunderstood - there is obviously some extra code outside this loop that you haven't included.  Either way... you need to loop through your board and check that it isn't full.   You need to change the NULL line to `if position != 'X' and  position != '0' : # Your board position is empty`

Comment: Sorry... this is a pretty big project and I didn't want to put the entirety of my code online, I am not able to private message yet your I would send my code to you. I just did what you told me to and it just stops the game before all the spots are full :( I am soooo beyond frustrated.. sorry if I confused you. (And thanks for all the help so far I really appreciate it!)

Comment: probably the easiest way of debugging it is to print out the board at various points in your code.  you should be able to work out what it is supposed to show at different points.  

Frustration is a key skill in programming.

Comment: Well just one way to optimize it is to use a standard value when the spots are empty (when the program starts, do this: ) `for i in board: board[i] = None` or `board[i] = 'empty'` or something of the sort, instead of doing `if board[_position_] != 1 and board[_position_] != 0`. Then, to check if the space is empty (if the computer can go there), simply do this: `if board[_position_]=='empty': #code to move`

Comment: My board is a list, and basically when the person selects a spot, it puts the 'X' or the 'O' if they are the computer, over that spot in the list.  so when I put the for loop in it seems like it should work to me, but when I run it, the break that I put in the for loop happens when there are still spots not taken :( and @F3AR3DLEGEND the problem is that the board is how the user chooses what spot to pick so for example I say pick a spot, then they input 1 and it goes in the top middle spot, you see what I mean? If I make them nothing then that kind of breaks the program. :(

Comment: You can just create a variable that tracks the moves, like such: `moves = 0 #at start of code` then after every move `moves += 1`. In the loop, add `if moves == 9: #code to end game/check for win`. You shouldn't really need a loop though... I've made a simple Tic Tac Toe AI (that plays intelligently) that can never be beat (it's in Scratch though---for the simple use of a GUI) without a single loop...

Comment: Dang that is skill right there my friend! @F3AR3DLEGEND Yeah I tried that, I tried putting playerturn as a variable and adding one after the computer makes a move and after the player makes a move but its no bueno it doesnt work :(( I think I just suck at life lol

Comment: Note to anyone still reading this and trying to help me, I somewhat got it working. Thanks for all your guys help!!

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning, the game is not done. When someone wins, the game is done. When 9 stones are played, the game is done. If the game is done, don't play any more.